# Fastest way to xor all integers in a string

Tags: python, performance, complexity-theory, xor

I am trying to find the fastest way of xor'ing all integers(numerals actually) in a string consecutively. The problem makes me feel that there is an simple and a fast answer I just can't think of. But here what I came up with so far.

**Setup:**

```
from operator import xor
a = "123"
```

- Regular loop

  ```
  val = 0
  for i in a:
      val = val ^ int(i)
  print val
  ```
- `operations.xor` with `reduce`

  ```
  reduce(xor, map(int, list(a)))
  ```

I expected the second one to be faster but when the string grows, the difference is almost none. Is there a faster way ?

**Note1:** And I would like to know if it is possible using just the integer as `123` instead of the string `"123"`. That would be unlogical because I need a list of integers, however sometimes interesting answers appear from places you never expect.

**Edit:** Here is the results from the methods suggested so far.

```
import timeit

setup = """
from operator import xor

a = "124"
b = 124
"""

p1 = """
val = 0
for i in a:
    val = val ^ int(i)
val
"""

p2 = """
reduce(xor, map(int, list(a)))
"""

p3 = """
val = 0
for i in xrange(3):
    val = val ^ (b % 10)
    b /= 10
val
"""

p4 = """
15 & reduce(xor, map(ord, a))
"""
print 1, timeit.timeit(p1, setup=setup, number = 100000)
print 2, timeit.timeit(p2, setup=setup, number = 100000)
print 3, timeit.timeit(p3, setup=setup, number = 100000)
print 4, timeit.timeit(p4, setup=setup, number = 100000)

# Gives
1 0.251768243842
2 0.377706036384
3 0.0885620849347
4 0.140079894386
```

Please also note that using `int(a)` instead of `b` in process 3 makes it slower than 4.

Comment: Your second one is essentially doing the exact same thing as the first one, but in one line

Comment: You know sometimes using built-ins make the code faster. So I tried it.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use a base 10 decimal number and modulo and divide out individual numbers? Not sure if that's better than casting a string, though

Comment: if you have an integer as input instead of a list, you basically take each digit one after the other by using a modulo and a division

Comment: What happens if you try `val ^= int(i)` ?  It might do it in place and not need an extra allocation.

Comment: I tried dmitry, it failed. And modulo seems like a good idea, thank you.

Comment: Failed to speed up or failed because the syntax is illegal?

Comment: there is no `ixor` defined for int, so `a ^= b` does exactly `a = a ^ b`

Comment: The `⁼^ operator and other augmetned assignemtn operators do not operate in place for Python integers. Numbers are always imutable objects - when yu perform an operation, you have a new number.

Comment: I meant the native implementation might do it in place since int is a built-in type.

Comment: If the list is very long, itertools.imap instead of map might help.  But if it's short, the preallocation of the ints probably doesn't have any speed overhead.

Comment: @jsbueno, in Python 3 `int` is a large number (an object) if it needs to be.  So it may need a new object instance to be allocated if it's not modified in place.

Comment: Doesn't the value in the `xrange(3)` in P3 need to be adjusted to the number in question (i.e. via a `log10(b)` or some such) -- it looks like you're using a three digit loop on a six digit number.

Comment: @cdlane you are correct, the easy way is just using `len(a)` however this code is not the solution for my problem just an example for time testing so this is not an issue here.(There is no six digit number btw number is 124)

Comment: fastest way is write it in C

Comment: It's an issue in that there is time overhead in coming up with that constant given a random input and that time should be accounted for when comparing solutions.  See my augmented solution that includes a numerical approach that gets around the constant issue.

Comment: If you're working with very large integers, I believe the string-based approaches will soundly beat the numeric ones as the number grows from 10,000 digits to 100,000 digits.

Answer (score 1):

On my (Python 3) system, this rework of the solution runs measureably faster than those shown:

```
from operator import xor
from functools import reduce

print(15 & reduce(xor, map(ord, a)))
```

If we know they are all digits, `15 & ord('5')` pulls out the bits we need with less overhead than `int('5')`.  And we can delay the logical "and", doing it just once at the end.

To use a number instead of a string, you can do:

```
b = 31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164

val = 0

while b:
    b, modulo = divmod(b, 10)
    val ^= modulo

print(val)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed faster than the methods I proposed. But as asserted in the comments, it is better to use directly the number rather than the string. But for the question I posted, your solution is so far the best approach.

Comment: Don't you need to `xor` with ord('0') if the number of digits is odd?

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich, I'm tossing the high order bits with the final `15 &` so I don't see how that's necessary but I'm open to an explanation.

Comment: @cdlane.  The ASCII value of '0' is 0x30.  So `ord('0') & 15' will produce 0.  But `ord('0') ^ ord('8') ^ ord('7')` is 0x3F.  `0x3F & 15` will be 15.  Actually, I think the whole method won't work.  If your strings are '00', '88', '77', then xor of only the digits in their perspective places (and then only keeping the last 4 bits) would produce 0x0F0F, which is not equal to 88 ^ 77.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich, `15 & (ord('0') ^ ord('8') ^ ord('7'))` is 15, as is `int('0') ^ int('8') ^ int('7')` so the method holds up for your first example.  Your second example isn't applicable since we're only processing individual digits, not two at a time.

Comment: @cdlane, i was reading it as xor'ing multiple numbers represented as decimal integers in a list of strings.  I just re-read it and you are right.  It's asking about 1 multi-digit string.  Since all the digits will be contained in the lower nibble (again because '0' is 0x30), your method will work.